# How to Find all Leaf Nodes Without Siblings Using BeautifulSoup (Python)?

Tags: python, html, dom, beautifulsoup, siblings

I want to preprocess HTML documents using `bs4` and need a way to find all leaf nodes in an HTML document that do not have siblings.

```py
from typing import List
import bs4

def _is_leaf_node(tag: bs4.Tag) -> bool:
    if isinstance(tag, bs4.NavigableString):
        return False
    if len(tag.find_all(text=False)) > 0:
        return False
    return True

def _has_sibling_nodes(tag: bs4.Tag) -> bool:
    if tag.previous_sibling is not None:
        return True
    if tag.next_sibling is not None:
        return True
    return False

_is_leaf_node_without_siblings = lambda node: _is_leaf_node(node) and not _has_sibling_nodes(node)
_is_leaf_node_without_siblings.__name__ = "_is_leaf_node_without_siblings"

def _find_leaf_nodes_without_siblings(soup: bs4.BeautifulSoup) -> List[bs4.Tag]:
    leaf_nodes_without_siblings = soup.find_all(_is_leaf_node_without_siblings)
    return list(leaf_nodes_without_siblings)

def main():
    html = """<html>
                  <body>
                      <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Test</li>
                            <li>Test</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <span>Test</span>
                      </div>
                  </body>
              </html>"""
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    print(_find_leaf_nodes_without_siblings(soup))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Currently my implementation returns `[]` but it should return
`[<span>Test</span>]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using `previous_sibling`, which returns *text nodes* as well. Note that `<span>Test</span>` has whitespace around it, so technically it has siblings. If you want the previous sibling *element* returned, do `find_previous_sibling()` instead. Ditto for `next_sibling`.

(The `find_*()` methods return *elements* when no parameters are passed; it seems like a criminally undocumented feature as I don't see it mentioned in the docs(?))

Tip: I'd call "leaf node without siblings" a *brat*, as children without siblings are often spoiled brats. It'd make the code shorter.

Tip: Alternatively, use xpath: `//*[position()=1 and position()=last()][not(*)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should return the expected result, with less complexity:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '''
<html>
  <body>
      <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Test</span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print([el for el in soup.find_all() if (len(el.find_next_siblings()) == 0 and 
                                        len(el.find_previous_siblings()) == 0 and 
                                        len(el.contents) == 1 and 
                                        isinstance(el.contents[0], NavigableString)) or (len(el.find_next_siblings()) == 0 and 
                                                                                         len(el.find_previous_siblings()) == 0 and 
                                                                                         len(el.contents) == 0)])
```

Resulting in:

```
[<span>Test</span>]
```

This covers both scenarios where leaf node is empty, or not (has text).

Comment: Lengthy, and not very readable. Detect leaves with `not elt.find()`, use `find_next_sibling`, not `find_next_siblings` (as you don't need all the elements), create predicates with meaningful names (as it's not a sin).

Comment: Agree with you and welcome your criticism, but: it's functional, not expensive, logic is based on counting the list elements, hence `find_next_siblings`, and I could move on to my next nested form in Django. So it's probably not that bad. And as list comprehension goes, it's probably not that slow either.